# How to use Laravel Passport with a custom username column

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

Now I'm using something like that for authenticating the user on my base site:

```
if (Auth::attempt($request->only(['id', 'password']))) {
            //
}
```

How can I modify this code for using custom column as username?
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#password-grant-tokens

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can use findForPassport method in your user model.

This method take username as argument, and return user model

For example:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    // ... some code

    public function findForPassport($username) {
        return $this->where('id', $username)->first();
    }
}
```

Comment: How about if the password is also stored in a separate database table? Or if   the credentials are validated by a third party API (under the hood)?

Comment: If your custom colum is called `username` you may want to use `return $this->where('username','=', $username)->first();`

Comment: what if i have to login with email and mobile number both

Comment: @swatantra you can use something like
`$this->where(fn($q) => $q->where('email', $username)->orWhere('phone', $username));`

Comment: Yeah, exactly I have already done that and it helps, Thanks

Answer (score 10):

A bit too late to answer, but I've been having a hard time trying to figure this out, so for the sake of completeness and to maybe help others in the future.

If you take a look to [this part of passport's code](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/master/src/Bridge/UserRepository.php#L49) you'll see that it also looks for a `validateForPassportPasswordGrant` method, so in addition to Alexander's answer, that's how you can authenticate an user using custom fields.

Hope it helps someone.