# Laravel Passport Scopes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport, scopes

I am a bit confused about the part of the Laravel scope.

I have a user model and table.

How can I assign a user the role of user, customer and/or admin.

I have an SPA with Vue and Laravel API backend. I use https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript

```
    Passport::tokensCan([
        'user' => 'User',
        'customer' => 'Customer',
        'admin' => 'Admin',
    ]);
```

How can I assign which user model has which scope(s)?

Or are scopes not the same as roles?

How would you implement this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The above answer by Leonardo worked for me with the addition of the following: use AuthenticatesUsers { login as protected traitlogin; } public function login(Request $request) { $request->request->add(['email' => $request->username]); return $this->traitlogin($request); }

Comment: hope this answer can help to to other https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45250407/custom-laravel-passport-check

Answer (score 79, accepted):

> Or are scopes not the same as roles?

The biggest difference between the two is the context they apply to. Role-based Access Control (RBAC) governs the access control of a user when using the web application **directly**, while Oauth-2 scope governs the access to the API resources for an **[external client](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2#oauth-roles)** on behalf of a user.

> How can i assign which user model has which scope(s)?

In general Oauth flow, a user (as a resource owner) is requested to authorize a client on things that it can and cannot do on his/her behalf, these are what you called **scope**. On **successful authorization** the scope being requested by the client will be **[assigned to the generated token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#assigning-scopes-to-tokens)** not to the user per se.

Depending on which Oauth grant flow that you choose, the client should include the scope on its request. In Authorization code grant flow the scope should be included on HTTP GET query parameter when redirecting the user to authorization page, while on Password grant flow the scope must be included in HTTP POST body parameter to request a token.

> How would you implement this?

This is an example with Password grant flow, with assumption that you completed the **[laravel/passport](https://laravel.com/docs/master/passport#installation)** setup beforehand

Define scopes for both admin and user role. Be specific as you can, for example: admin can manage-order and user only read it.

```
// in AuthServiceProvider boot
Passport::tokensCan([
    'manage-order' => 'Manage order scope'
    'read-only-order' => 'Read only order scope'
]);
```

Prepare the REST controller

```
// in controller
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class OrderController extends Controller
{   
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        // allow listing all order only for token with manage order scope
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // allow storing a newly created order in storage for token with manage order scope
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        // allow displaying the order for token with both manage and read only scope
    }
}
```

Assign the route with api guard and scope

```
// in api.php
Route::get('/api/orders', 'OrderController@index')
    ->middleware(['auth:api', 'scopes:manage-order']);
Route::post('/api/orders', 'OrderController@store')
    ->middleware(['auth:api', 'scopes:manage-order']);
Route::get('/api/orders/{id}', 'OrderController@show')
    ->middleware(['auth:api', 'scopes:manage-order, read-only-order']);
```

And when issuing a token check the user role first and grant the scope based on that role. To achieve this, we need an extra controller that use AuthenticatesUsers trait to provide login endpoint.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class ApiLoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {               
        // implement your user role retrieval logic, for example retrieve from `roles` database table
        $role = $user->checkRole();

        // grant scopes based on the role that we get previously
        if ($role == 'admin') {
            $request->request->add([
                'scope' => 'manage-order' // grant manage order scope for user with admin role
            ]);
        } else {
            $request->request->add([
                'scope' => 'read-only-order' // read-only order scope for other user role
            ]);
        }

        // forward the request to the oauth token request endpoint
        $tokenRequest = Request::create(
            '/oauth/token',
            'post'
        );
        return Route::dispatch($tokenRequest);
    }
}
```

Add route for api login endpoint

```
//in api.php
Route::group('namespace' => 'Auth', function () {
    Route::post('login', 'ApiLoginController@login');
});
```

Instead of doing POST to /oauth/token route, POST to the api login endpoint that we provided before

```
// from client application
$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

$response = $http->post('http://your-app.com/api/login', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => 'client-id',
        'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
        'username' => 'user@email.com',
        'password' => 'my-password',
    ],
]);

return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
```

Upon successful authorization, an access_token and a refresh_token based on scope that we define before will be issued for the client application. Keep that somewhere and include the token to the HTTP header whenever making a request to the API.

```
// from client application
$response = $client->request('GET', '/api/my/index', [
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$accessToken,
    ],
]);
```

The API now should return

```
{"error":"unauthenticated"}
```

whenever a token with under privilege is used to consumed restricted endpoint.

Comment: @RaymondLagonda Thanks for the answer. I am facing one issue - on Laravel 5.3, when you use "AuthenticatesUser" trait, the "login" method within the trait fails validation. It doesn't even reach "authenticated" method. Does Laravel Passport use same authentication trait?

Comment: @JaimilPrajapati I think I had a similar issue.  Normal login uses email but api login uses username.  Sneak this into your ApiLoginController...

    $request->request->add(['username' => $request->email]);
    $tokenRequest = Request::create(
   '/oauth/token',
   'post'
  );

Comment: @JaimilPrajapati I think that warrant another question. But here are things to check out: make sure no guard is applied to the api login route, if you're using custom column check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39194917/how-to-use-laravel-passport-with-a-custom-username-column as of now, password grant flow only take username column and lastly you can always check which line is failing in the login method in AuthenticatesUsers.php.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I ended up re-writing Authentication mechanism to apply required logic, before adding appropriate scope. @RaymondLagonda Your idea of intercepting Login request, and adding scope is amazing!

Comment: I think something is missing related to CORS feature, any ideas?

Comment: Why the ApiLoginController@login method is missing?

Comment: In the controller where you attach scopes based on the user role. Are these the permissions of the role?

Answer (score 5):

Implement the Raymond Lagonda response and it works very well, just to be careful with the following.
You need to override some methods from AuthenticatesUsers traits in ApiLoginController:

```
    /**
     * Send the response after the user was authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        // $request->session()->regenerate(); // coment this becose api routes with passport failed here.

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
                ?: response()->json(["status"=>"error", "message"=>"Some error for failes authenticated method"]);

    }

    /**
     * Get the failed login response instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->json([
                                "status"=>"error", 
                                "message"=>"Autentication Error", 
                                "data"=>[
                                    "errors"=>[
                                        $this->username() => Lang::get('auth.failed'),
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]);
    }
```

If you changed the login: username field to a custom username field eg: e_mail. You must refine the username method as in your LoginController.
Also you have to redefine and edit the methods: validateLogin, attemptLogin, credentials since once the login is validated, the request is forwarded to passport and must be called username.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a little late, but if you're consuming a backend API in an SPA using the `CreateFreshApiToken` in web middleware, then you can simply add an 'admin' middleware to your app:

`php artisan make:middleware Admin`

Then in `\App\Http\Middleware\Admin` do the following:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::user()->role() !== 'admin') {
        return response(json_encode(['error' => 'Unauthorised']), 401)
            ->header('Content-Type', 'text/json');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Make sure you have added the `role` method to `\App\User` to retrieve the users role.

Now all you need to do is register your middleware in `app\Http\Kernel.php` `$routeMiddleware`, like so:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // Other Middleware
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,
];
```

And add that to your route in `routes/api.php`

```
Route::middleware(['auth:api','admin'])->get('/customers','Api\CustomersController@index');
```

Now if you try to access the api without permission you will receive a "401 Unauthorized" error, which you can check for and handle in your app.

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to get this into working, with @RaymondLagonda solution, for **Laravel 5.5** with **Sentinel**, but it should, also work, without Sentinel.

The solution needs some class methods overriding (so please keep that in mind, for future updates), and adds some protection to your api routes (not exposing client_secret for example).

First step, is to modify your `ApiLoginController` in order to add construct  function:

```
public function __construct(Request $request){
        $oauth_client_id = env('PASSPORT_CLIENT_ID');
        $oauth_client = OauthClients::findOrFail($oauth_client_id);

        $request->request->add([
            'email' => $request->username,
            'client_id' => $oauth_client_id,
            'client_secret' => $oauth_client->secret]);
    }
```

In this example, you need to define var ('PASSPORT_CLIENT_ID') in your .env and create OauthClients Model, but you can safely skip this by putting your proper test values here.

One thing to notice, is that we are setting `$request->email` value to username, just to stick to Oauth2 convention.

Second step is, to override, `sendLoginResponse` method which is causing errors like `Session storage not set`, we don't need sessions here, cause it is api.

```
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
//        $request->session()->regenerate();

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
            ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

Third step is, to modify your authenticated methods as suggested by @RaymondLagonda. You need to write your own logic here, and especially configure your scopes.

And final step (in case you are using Sentinel) is to modify `AuthServiceProvider`. Add

```
$this->app->rebinding('request', function ($app, $request) {
            $request->setUserResolver(function () use ($app) {
                 return \Auth::user();
//                return $app['sentinel']->getUser();
            });
        });
```

just after `$this->registerPolicies();` in boot method.

After these steps you should be able, to get your api working, by providing username ('this will always be email, in this implementation'), password and grant_type='password'

At this point, you can add to middlewares scopes `scopes:...` or `scope:...` to protect your routes.

I hope, it is going to really help...

Answer (score 3):

With @RaymondLagonda solution. If you are getting a class scopes not found error, add the following middleware to the `$routeMiddleware` property of your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file:

```
'scopes' => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckScopes::class, 
'scope' => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckForAnyScope::class,`
```

Also, if you are getting the error `Type error: Too few arguments to function`, you should be able to get the `$user` from the request like below.

(I am using laratrust for managing roles)

```
public function login(Request $request)
{

    $email = $request->input('username');
    $user = User::where('email','=',$email)->first();

    if($user && $user->hasRole('admin')){
        $request->request->add([
            'scope' => 'manage-everything'
        ]);
    }else{
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthorized'],403);
    }

    $tokenRequest = Request::create(
      '/oauth/token',
      'post'
    );

    return Route::dispatch($tokenRequest);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this, this question was riddling my mind for a while! I took Raymond Lagonda's solution customised it a little for Laravel 5.6, using the built-in rate limiting, using a single `thirdparty` client (or be more custom if needed), while still giving each user a list of permissions (scopes).

- Uses Laravel Passport `password` grant and follows Oauth flow
- Gives you ability to set roles (scopes) for different users
- don't expose/release client ID or client secret, only the user's username (email) and password, pretty much a [password](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#creating-a-password-grant-client) grant, minus the client/grant stuff

## Examples at bottom

> routes/api.php

```
    Route::group(['namespace' => 'ThirdParty', 'prefix' => 'thirdparty'], function () {
        Route::post('login', 'ApiLoginController@login');
    });
```

> ThirdParty/ApiLoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\ThirdParty;

use Hash;
use App\User;
use App\ThirdParty;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class ApiLoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Thirdparty login method to handle different
     * clients logging in for different reasons,
     * we assign each third party user scopes
     * to assign to their token, so they
     * can perform different API tasks
     * with the same token.
     *
     * @param  Request $request
     * @return Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function login(Request $request)
    {
        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        $user = $this->validateUserLogin($request);

        $client = ThirdParty::where(['id' => config('thirdparties.client_id')])->first();

        $request->request->add([
            'scope' => $user->scopes,
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => $client->id,
            'client_secret' => $client->secret
        ]);

        return Route::dispatch(
            Request::create('/oauth/token', 'post')
        );
    }

    /**
     * Validate the users login, checking
     * their username/password
     *
     * @param  Request $request
     * @return User
     */
    public function validateUserLogin($request)
    {
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        $username = $request->username;
        $password = $request->password;

        $user = User::where(['email' => $username])->first();

        abort_unless($user, 401, 'Incorrect email/password.');

        $user->setVisible(['password']);

        abort_unless(Hash::check($password, $user->password), 401, 'Incorrect email/password.');

        return $user;
    }
}
```

> config/thirdparties.php

```
<?php

return [
    'client_id' => env('THIRDPARTY_CLIENT_ID', null),
];
```

> ThirdParty.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ThirdParty extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'oauth_clients';
}
```

> .env

```
## THIRDPARTIES
THIRDPARTY_CLIENT_ID=3
```

> php artisan make:migration add_scope_to_users_table --table=users

```
        // up
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->text('scopes')->nullable()->after('api_access');
        });
        // down
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('scopes');
        });
```

(note: `api_access` is a flag which decides whether a user can login to the website/frontend portion of the app, to view dashboards/records etc.),

> routes/api.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth.client:YOUR_SCOPE_HERE', 'throttle:60,1']], function () {
    ...routes...
});
```

> MySQL - Users scopes

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `name`, `email`, `password`, `remember_token`, `api_access`, `scopes`)
VALUES
    (5, '2019-03-19 19:27:08', '2019-03-19 19:27:08', '', 'hello@email.tld', 'YOUR_HASHED_PASSWORD', NULL, 1, 'YOUR_SCOPE_HERE ANOTHER_SCOPE_HERE');
```

> MySQL - `ThirdParty` Oauth Client

```
INSERT INTO `oauth_clients` (`id`, `user_id`, `name`, `secret`, `redirect`, `personal_access_client`, `password_client`, `revoked`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
VALUES
    (3, NULL, 'Thirdparty Password Grant Client', 'YOUR_SECRET', 'http://localhost', 0, 1, 0, '2019-03-19 19:12:37', '2019-03-19 19:12:37');
```

> cURL - Logging in/requesting a token

```
curl -X POST \
  http://site.localhost/api/v1/thirdparty/login \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Accept-Charset: application/json' \
  -F username=hello@email.tld \
  -F password=YOUR_UNHASHED_PASSWORD
```

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 604800,
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciO...",
    "refresh_token": "def502008a75cd2cdd0dad086..."
}
```

Use longlived access_token/refresh_token as normal!

> Accessing forbidden scope

```
{
    "data": {
        "errors": "Invalid scope(s) provided."
    },
    "meta": {
        "code": 403,
        "status": "FORBIDDEN"
    }
}
```