# How to handle client_id and client_secret for Password Grant Tokens in Passport

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am trying to figure out how to handle the Password Grant Tokens in Passport package. Should i store the client_id and client_secret in .env file or fetch the values direct from the database while requesting for a the token?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you are finally trying to achieve.

**Passport** tokens are always stored in **DB**, and this is the right place to retrieve them (unless you are optimizing your production app, to gain less db load).

So, if you want to build an **api** endpoint, you can safely store **PASSPORT_CLIENT_ID** in your .env.

And then, in your controller, you can easily retrieve all data that you may need.

How to do it? Please read [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436509/laravel-passport-scopes/48088463#48088463), on how you can embed this in your **laravel** controller.

**Passport** is built on top of [oauth2 server](https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/) which has loads of features.

Most likely you won't need them all, so you can stick to the basic **jwt authorization** as in this case.

This approach would enable you to test your code against different **CI** environments, while not sharing any specific keys/tokens in your **VCS**, which is definitely a good practice.

Final note... **Passport** makes packages like dingo, tymon jwt, etc.. useless, cause it has almost everything packed in, and what really important is, this is the **official Laravel package**.

Answer (score 1):

While you certainly can store the values inside your .env file, you should think these tokens as secrets you grant to other developers who want to use your API. What if everyday 50 developers want to register to use your API, will you add them by hand to your .env file? If it's only you / your company this kan be "ok", but I would store them in the database for scalability.