# Custom Laravel Passport Check

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

Is There anyway to add or pass 1 more variable to findForPassport ?

In default laravel passport login, i only can pass 2 variable (username, password),but I want to pass 1 more variable and check in findForPassport if that user is belong other table or not .

Comment: may be this could help you https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/81

Comment: thank you . maybe i dont need because now i found it by my own

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I hope this answer can help to other. 
If you want to add variable and pass this variable to findPassport function in User Authenticate model , you need to update 3 class in passport :
  - **UserRepositoryInterface** in vendor\league\oauth2-server\src\Repositories\UserRepositoryInterface
  - **PasswordGrant** in vendor\league\oauth2-server\src\Grant\PasswordGrant
  - **UserRepository** in vendor\laravel\passport\src\Bridge\UserRepository
in the example code I will add parent variable and code will look like this

+in UserRepositoryInterface class

```
interface UserRepositoryInterface extends RepositoryInterface
{

/**
 * Get a user entity.
 *
 * @param string                $username
 * @param string                $password
 * @param string                $grantType    The grant type used
 * @param ClientEntityInterface $clientEntity
 *
 * @return UserEntityInterface
 */
public function getUserEntityByUserCredentials(
    $username,
    $password,
    $parent,                           <------variable example 
    $grantType,
    ClientEntityInterface $clientEntity
);
}
```

+in PasswordGrant class

```
class PasswordGrant extends AbstractGrant{ 
protected function validateUser(ServerRequestInterface $request, ClientEntityInterface $client)
{
    $username = $this->getRequestParameter('username', $request);
    if (is_null($username)) {
        throw OAuthServerException::invalidRequest('username');
    }

    $password = $this->getRequestParameter('password', $request);
    if (is_null($password)) {
        throw OAuthServerException::invalidRequest('password');
    }

  /**
  * Get a user parent.
  * varaible example 
  */
    $parent = $this->getRequestParameter('parent', $request);  
    if (is_null($parent)) {
        throw OAuthServerException::invalidRequest('password');
    }

    $user = $this->userRepository->getUserEntityByUserCredentials(
        $username,
        $password,
        $parent,                          <--- variable example get from request
        $this->getIdentifier(),
        $client
    );
    if ($user instanceof UserEntityInterface === false) {
        $this->getEmitter()->emit(new RequestEvent(RequestEvent::USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED, $request));

        throw OAuthServerException::invalidCredentials();
    }

    return $user;
}  }
```

+in UserRepository class

```
class UserRepository implements UserRepositoryInterface
{

public function getUserEntityByUserCredentials($username, $password, $parent, $grantType, ClientEntityInterface $clientEntity) 
/*add 1more parameter that implement from UserRepositoryInterface*/
{
    $provider = config('auth.guards.api.provider');

    if (is_null($model = config('auth.providers.'.$provider.'.model'))) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Unable to determine authentication model from configuration.');
    }

    if (method_exists($model, 'findForPassport')) {
        $user = (new $model)->findForPassport($username,$parent);    <--- finally we pass parent variable to findForPassport here
    } else {
        $user = (new $model)->where('email', $username)->first();
    }

    if (! $user) {
        return;
    } elseif (method_exists($user, 'validateForPassportPasswordGrant')) {
        if (! $user->validateForPassportPasswordGrant($password)) {
            return;
        }
    } elseif (! $this->hasher->check($password, $user->getAuthPassword())) {
        return;
    }

    return new User($user->getAuthIdentifier());
}
}
```

then u can get $parent value from parameter in findForPassport .but make sure you return value as eloquent User .if you want to join table , you can look my example code below

```
class User extends Authenticatable{

..........
public function findForPassport($identifier,$parent) {
    $a = $this
        ->Join('role as r', 'r.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->get();
    return $a->where('name', $identifier)->where('role_id',$parent)->first();

  }
}
```

Comment: Modifying vendor files? Really? This answer almost gave me a cancer >_<

Comment: It is never ever a good ideia to modify vendor files, anytime the composer updated all changes will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

From [the link to passport issue #81 pointed by @Arun in OP](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/81#issuecomment-281020525):

> There's probably a better way of doing this now but I extended the PassportServiceProvider and copied the registerAuthorizationServer function so that I could register my own grant type.
>
> Swap out the provider in config\app.php with your new one:
>
> ```
> 'providers' => [
>  //Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class,
>     App\Providers\PassportClientCredentialsServiceProvider::class,
> ```
>
> **Updated registerAuthorizationServer function that includes new grant option:**
>
> ```
> protected function registerAuthorizationServer()
>   {
>     parent::registerAuthorizationServer();
>     $this->app->singleton(AuthorizationServer::class, function () {
>       return tap($this->makeAuthorizationServer(), function ($server) {
>         /**
>          * @var $server AuthorizationServer
>          */
>         $server->enableGrantType(
>           new ClientCredentialsGrant(), Passport::tokensExpireIn()
>         );
>         /** custom grant type */
>         $server->enableGrantType(
>           new PasswordOverrideGrant(
>             $this->app->make(UserRepository::class),
>             $this->app->make(RefreshTokenRepository::class)
>           ), Passport::tokensExpireIn()
>         );
>
>         $server->enableGrantType(
>           $this->makeAuthCodeGrant(), Passport::tokensExpireIn()
>         );
>
>         $server->enableGrantType(
>           $this->makeRefreshTokenGrant(), Passport::tokensExpireIn()
>         );
>
>         $server->enableGrantType(
>           $this->makePasswordGrant(), Passport::tokensExpireIn()
>         );
>
>         $server->enableGrantType(
>           new PersonalAccessGrant(), new \DateInterval('P1Y')
>         );
>       });
>     });
>   }
> ```
>
> PasswordOverrideGrant looks like this:
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> namespace App\Auth;
>
> use App\User;
> use League\OAuth2\Server\Entities\ClientEntityInterface;
> use League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException;
> use League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\PasswordGrant;
> use League\OAuth2\Server\RequestEvent;
> use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
>
> class PasswordOverrideGrant extends PasswordGrant
> {
>   protected function validateUser(ServerRequestInterface $request, ClientEntityInterface $client)
>   {
>     $username = $this->getRequestParameter('username', $request);
>     if (is_null($username)) {
>       throw OAuthServerException::invalidRequest('username');
>     }
>
>     $custom_hash_token = $this->getRequestParameter('hash_token', $request);
>     if (is_null($custom_hash_token)) {
>       throw OAuthServerException::invalidRequest('identifier');
>     }
>
>     $credentials = [
>       'username' => $username,
>       'hash_token' => $custom_hash_token,
>     ];
>
>     $user = User::where($credentials)->first();
>
>     if ($user instanceof User === false) {
>       $this->getEmitter()->emit(new RequestEvent(RequestEvent::USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED, $request));
>
>       throw OAuthServerException::invalidCredentials();
>     }
>
>     return $user;
>   }
>   public function getIdentifier()
>   {
>     return 'password_override';
>   }
> }
> ```