# Laravel - Create API with Header Key

Tags: laravel, api, token, lumen

I'm new in laravel, I want to create basic Laravel API without login authentication to get the token. Is there a way to create a static API token that can access fron header?, any answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **Laravel Passport** definitely.

Documentation of **Passport** and underlying **Oauth2 Server**, could be a way better.

But despite this fact, it is a way to go, for building real, good working **API**.

If you want to use `password grant token` only (which is the most used scenario) then this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436509/laravel-passport-scopes/48088463#48088463) might be helpful to you...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using  Laravel Passport. Read the documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport