# How to consume an authenticated API with Axios

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios, laravel-passport

I'm trying to build an application using Vue and Laravel. I currently use passport authentication within Laravel for user authentication. However, when I try to make a post request from a vue component using axio, I get 401 unauthorized, even if I am currently logged in.

Here is some example code:

**1. Get request from the vue component**

```
    getEvents() {
      axios
        .get("/api/calendar")
        .then(resp => (this.events = resp.data.data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err.response.data));
    }
```

**2. Laravel routes**

```php
Route::apiResource('/calendar', 'CalendarController')->middleware('auth:api');
```

**3. Calendar controller associated with the get request above**

```php
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return CalendarResource::collection(Calendar::all());
    }
```

I've spent hours with this issue and everything I have found simply doesn't work. So any help at all is extremely appeciated.

*edit:*

**Extra details**

I am using Laravel 5.8.35.

In regards to passport, I am using this documentation laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport and followed the installationm front end quick start and deploying steps.

*second edit:*

**Full code on github**

Here is the full project on github incase this can help. https://github.com/CMHayden/akal.app/tree/feature/Calendar

Comment: What authentication method do you have in Laravel? Do you use JWT?

Comment: I use the laravel passport authentication, just following the documentation for it, so I am unsure. I know I use bearer tokens when testing with postman if this helps?

Comment: Firstly, what version of Laravel are you using? Secondly, which of the various flows from the documentation have you used to authenticate your user i.e. are you using the password grant or the "Consuming Your API With JavaScript" approach, or something different. It would definitely help if you can explain the steps you've gone through in a little more detail.

Comment: Hey there, sorry for the lack of information. 

I am using Laravel 5.8.35. 

In regards to passport, I am using this documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport and followed the installationm front end quick start and deploying steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made some changes to your project, here is the github repository https://github.com/AzafoCossa/ProFix, hope it works.

Open AuthServiceProvider.php file, add `Passport::routes()` to `boot()` function and open auth.php file, update 'api' guard from `'driver'=>'token'` to `'driver'=>'passport'` and finally open Kernel.php file, add this middleware:

```
'web' => [
   // Other middleware...
   \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
],
```

Answer (score 1):

Please confirm if you've set the `meta` value for `csrf token` in the entry `html` or `blade` file

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Also the header for `axios` in the `bootstrap.js` file like this

```
window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

Comment: I can confirm. My app.blade has the csrf token meta tag and the bootstrap.js does include the axios code.

Comment: Can you also check if the `auth token` is set and passing with the request header.

Comment: How would I be able to check this? I'm still pretty meh with javascript

Comment: Open the `Network` tab of your browser. Then filter it using `XHR`. Now when you reload the browser, you can see the http request you've made. On clicking on the request, it will show all the headers set.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help! So yes I can see a cookie which is laravel_token= and a bearer token, and I can see the xsrf token

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the correct middleware along with the other suggestions here

```
'web' => [
    // Other middleware...
    \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
],
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript

Also you shouldn't need these lines that you have in the bootstrap or calendar component. Passport will take care of that for you with http only cookies.

```
//send Authorization token with each request
axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
```

Comment: I have tried this but unfortunately it still doesn't want to work so I don't know what to do anymore

Answer (score 0):

All I did to the same problem is:

1. in User.php, added on head,

```
'use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;'
```

then inside the class, added

```
'HasApiTokens' to the line 'use Notifiable, HasRoles, HasApiTokens;'
```

1. In config>auth.php , changed 'driver'=>'token' to 'driver'=>'passport' under 'api' under 'guard'.

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

3. add the CreateFreshApiToken middleware to your web middleware group in your app/Http/Kernel.php file:

```
'web' => [
    // Other middleware...
    \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
],
```

Nothing else.
My axios request was: `axios.get('api/cities');`

It worked as I wanted. Only component can access the data. But no authenticated or unauthenticated user can access the data through direct url.

Answer (score -1):

If you are storing auth token in cookie then you can do as follows

```
let token = cookie.get("token");
//send Authorization token with each request
axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
axios
     .get("/api/calendar")
     .then(resp => console.log(resp.data))
     .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: I have tried this, however, when I check in the network tab I cannot find the authorization header. I also have a small confusion with the Cookie header which contains a laravel_token and a laravel_session and if it is possible something to do with this? Would this also only work through http and maybe just not work locally? Thanks again

Comment: The solution above I use with JWT and store the token in the cookie for future authorization. You can check all cookies, session storage, and local storage data in _Application_ tab. Use _Network_ tab to check the response sent from the server.

Comment: Unfortunetly this solution doesn't seem to want to work for me and I don't even understand why it won't work

Comment: See if this works out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436509/laravel-passport-scopes/40433000#40433000