# Laravel Passport: Custom column name SQL error

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am doing an API using Laravel's Passport, and whenever I send a request to one of my resources, I get this error:

```
{
    "message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `id` = 1 limit 1)",
    "exception": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",
    ...
}
```

We can see that it doesn't find the `id` column, that's because I renamed it to `USER_ID`.

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39194917/how-to-use-laravel-passport-with-a-custom-username-column), but I don't see how I could use it in my case.

I tried this in my `User.php` model:

```
public function findForPassport($username) {
    return $this->where('USER_ID', $username)->first();
}
```

But it didn't fix the problem.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: show us some code. How does the code gives you this issue look like?

Comment: Just curious, why choose `user_id` over `id`? `id` to me, is the more idiomatic choice

Comment: @Derek actually there are some database designs where you do this. In that case when you do a join or an union you don't need to specify the key anymore. Ex: Select * from users join roles instead of select * from users u join role r on r.user_id = u.id

Comment: It's to normalise the column names when doing junctures between 2 tables. I take the four first characters of the table's name. And when this is keys, ie primary keys or foreign keys, I make them upper case.

Comment: `protected $primaryKey = "user_id";` in your User model should fix this for you

Comment: @Derek Thank you, that fixed my problem. Now I have another problem but this is not on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derek's comment is correct, just set `protected $primaryKey = 'user_id'`.  If you're interested in the nuts and bolts of it though, read on:

That issue is actually not specific to Passport, it has more to do with the Auth Guard behavior, which is abstracted from Passport.

Laravel's out-of-the-box `App\User` Model extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`, which uses the `Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable` trait.  That trait is just a convenience for satisfying the conditions of the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` interface, one of which is to have basically a getter for whatever your username and password fields are.

This trait defaults the username field to be the same as that tables primary key.  But it doesn't have to be, if you were to override the `getAuthIdentifierName()` in your own Model class and make it return a field of your choosing.