# Laravel Passport: login using only username without password

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

In my project I'll validate user phone number by sending confirmation code with sms. After confirmation I must send login request to my laravel app. In [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/passport#requesting-password-grant-tokens) documentation has example request to login user:

```
$response = $http->post('http://your-app.com/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => 'client-id',
        'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
        'username' => 'taylor@laravel.com',
        'password' => 'my-password',
        'scope' => '',
    ],
]);
```

How I can here set as `username` user `phone` and remove `password`?

If `password` is required field in Laravel Passport then from client I can send any password and owerride requesting user `password` before `attempt` user credentials. But where I must owerride password?

I've tired change `LoginController` but not working.

**LoginController**

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        $this->username() => 'required|string'
    ]);
}

protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    $params = [
        'password' => '12345678',
    ];
    $request->request->add($params);
    return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
}

public function username()
{
    return 'phone';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `findForPassport` method in your user model.

it take username as argument, and return user model

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39194917/how-to-use-laravel-passport-with-a-custom-username-column)

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

    // Set as username any column from users table
    public function findForPassport($username) 
    {
        $customUsername = 'phone';
        return $this->where($customUsername, $username)->first();
    }
    // Owerride password here
    public function validateForPassportPasswordGrant($password)
    {
        $owerridedPassword = 'password';
        return Hash::check($password, $this->password);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've change my `User` model but when I enter wrong password with correct user phone then server return me error code `401` with error message `The user credentials were incorrect.`

Comment: I've set as `username` user phone like this: `return $this->where('phone', $username)->first();`